# Why am I getting the SIGABRT Error?

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I am trying to make a game kind of like Five Nights At Freddys for IPhones!  I know this error only occurs when I am calling on a Outlet that does not exist, but I am POSITIVE I don't have any labels that don't exist. 
Here is my Error if it helps at all..

[Here is the error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAOBL.png)

And here is my main.storyboard if again, it helps at all..

[The main.storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHPhc.png)

And here is the console:

```
2018-01-31 10:38:24.332509-0500 Code Orange[2606:253495] 
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one 
you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't 
expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints 
and fix it. 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000000854b0 UIImageView:0x7f86f1d0b3a0.width == 
375   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000009ba30 UIImageView:0x7f86f1d0b3a0.leading 
== UILayoutGuide:0x6000001b3160'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.leading   
(active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000009bda0 UIImageView:0x7f86f1d0b3a0.trailing 
== UILayoutGuide:0x6000001b3160'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.trailing   
(active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000009cf70 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' 
UIView:0x7f86f1d0bff0.width == 414   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000009bcb0 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-left' 
H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000001b3160'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'](LTR)   
(active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f86f1d0bff0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000009bd50 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-right' 
H:[UILayoutGuide:0x6000001b3160'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)   
(active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f86f1d0bff0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000000854b0 UIImageView:0x7f86f1d0b3a0.width == 
375   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to 
catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView 
listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2018-01-31 10:38:24.333733-0500 Code Orange[2606:253495] 
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one 
you don't want. 
Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't 
expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints 
and fix it. 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000000932e0 UIImageView:0x7f86f1d0b3a0.height 
== 667   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000009bdf0 UIImageView:0x7f86f1d0b3a0.bottom 
== UILayoutGuide:0x6000001b3160'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.bottom   
(active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000009be40 V:|-(0)-
[UIImageView:0x7f86f1d0b3a0]   (active, names: 
'|':UIView:0x7f86f1d0bff0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000009cfc0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' 
UIView:0x7f86f1d0bff0.height == 736   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000009bd00 'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide-bottom' 
V:[UILayoutGuide:0x6000001b3160'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide']-(0)-|   
(active, names: '|':UIView:0x7f86f1d0bff0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000000932e0 UIImageView:0x7f86f1d0b3a0.height == 
667   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to 
catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView 
listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2018-01-31 10:38:25.257696-0500 Code Orange[2606:253495] -[_SwiftValue 
spawnMonster]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000441320
2018-01-31 10:38:25.261123-0500 Code Orange[2606:253495] *** 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[_SwiftValue spawnMonster]: unrecognized selector sent to 
instance 0x600000441320'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010529e12b 
__exceptionPreprocess + 171
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104932f41 
objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010531f024 -
[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105220f78 
___forwarding___ + 1432
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105220958 
_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   Foundation                          0x000000010439ab1e 
__NSFireTimer + 83
6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010522e174 
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
7   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010522de32 
__CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1026
8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010522d9ea 
__CFRunLoopDoTimers + 266
9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105225404 
__CFRunLoopRun + 2308
10  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105224889 
CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
11  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010addc9c6 
GSEventRunModal + 62
12  UIKit                               0x000000010571c5d6 
UIApplicationMain + 159
13  Code Orange                         0x000000010401a747 main + 55
14  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000109749d81 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type 
NSException
(lldb)
```

Also.. I've looked through the console and I'm wondering if the constraints can cause this error.

Here is the code for the ViewController.swift file:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

//Variables
var temp:Int = 60
var battery:Int = 100
var monsterCount:Int = 0

//Outlets

//The main jump
@IBOutlet weak var mainJumpscare: UIImageView!

//Main background image
@IBOutlet weak var mainBackground: UIImageView!

//The battery and Temp display
@IBOutlet weak var BatteryDisplay: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var TempDisplay: UILabel!


//The timer variable
var updateTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: Selector(("spawnMonster")), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
//Other functions

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    mainJumpscare?.isHidden = true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//The spawning spawnMonster
func spawnMonster() {
    monsterCount += 1
    if monsterCount >= 5 {
        mainBackground.image = UIImage(named: "main-room-jumpTop")
    }
}

@IBAction func shockRoomsAction(_ sender: Any) {
}

}
```

[Here is proof that I imported the outlets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj3VL.png)

Comment: what is a `spawnMonster` method? When you call this method? Could you provide code of this method?

Comment: Sure! Just give me a sec..

Comment: There you go! Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the problem has nothing to do with outlets.  There are a few things wrong but the main issue, I believe, is that you're trying to start the timer before your controller is actually created, which results in a bad value for the `self` parameter.

Try this:

```
var updateTimer: Timer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mainJumpscare?.isHidden = true

    updateTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(spawnMonster), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func spawnMonster() {
    //  ...
}
```

Comment: That looks like it should work! I agree with you.. I just replaced my code with  that, although it didn't work at all. I got the same error... I even tried taking out the timer and see if anything would happen, I still just got the error.

Comment: When you say "same error", I get suspicious.  Can you show the exact line with "unrecognized selector" in it after you made the change?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't being clear.. I am not getting that error, I am getting the Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error...

Comment: OK...what does the debug console say this time?

Comment: Go here, I published it on google docs:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vSk5w-iJ6B-ryCScefYmoOjMOLYOdRCZdYKtClSbYdlCFFOnDZgAaEfA7-vr-DpxThWMt5NGfbV2xT0/pub

Comment: That's three more errors that have nothing to do with the original timer problem.  The fix for all of them is basically: make sure that the classes you reference in your storyboard actually match your code classes.